# Unable to compile Podfile "Missing input and no rule to build"

Tags: swift, xcode, podfile

I am currently unable to compile my podfile in Xcode10, and there doesn't seem to be much information online regarding how to fix this issue...

The current message I am getting is:

```
Showing All Messages
:-1: missing input '(File location)...Podfile.o' and no rule to build it
```

And this is my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'App' do
project '/Users/Oskilla/Desktop/Swift/App/App.xcodeproj'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
pod 'INSPhotoGallery'
end
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't compile a Podfile. You use the CocoaPods gem to install and setup a CocoaPods integrated workspace:
[Getting Started with CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

open terminal, `cd /toPodFileDir/`, then `pod install`

then open the **xcworkspace** file in your project folder and try to compile.

If you get errors after trying the above, let me know and I can edit.

Comment: You're welcome!  If this was the solution, you should upvote :)